# DELETED: Javascript regex look ahead or end of string

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to break the a series of numbers and separators into chapters and verses.
For example: '1:2-33; 333:4-55, 66:7-8', should match three groups:

```
chapter: '1', verses: '2-33; '
chapter: '333', verses: '4-55, '
chapter: '66', verses: '7-8'
```

I would expected this regular expression to do the job:

`/(?<chapter>\d+)\s*:(?<verses>.*?((?=\d+:)|$))?/gi`

But the last group fails to match verses, I get:

```
chapter: '1', verses: '2-33; '
chapter: '333', verses: '4-55, '
chapter: '66'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: On the other hand, I did [get all the matches](https://regex101.com/r/MTXudt/1).

Comment: Sorry, this question is not valid. The reason the last match was missing was accidental end of line character in the test string I entered in regex101.com tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the groups without a lookaround:

```
\b(?<chapter>\d+)\s*:(?<verses>\d+-\d+)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YSJKut/1)

Or for example matching either a comma or semicolon or assert the end of the string:

```
\b(?<chapter>\d+)\s*:(?<verses>\d+-\d+)(?:[,;]\s*|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8C2KoR/1)